# Внутренний класс vs. Статический вложенный

Tags: java

Всем привет!

Реализуя свой учебный **связанный список**, залез посмотреть как реализован **LinkedList** в пакете **java.util**, да бы последовать примеру. При виде этой красоты, у меня возникло пару вопросов:

1. С какой целью разработчики этого класса сделали класс **Node** вложенным и статическим, а класс **ListItr**
   внутренним, но не статическим?
2. Как так получается, что "*вроде бы*" находясь внутри статического контекста класса **Node**, мы получаем доступ через ключевое слово **this** к не статическим членам класса?

Ниже приведен фрагмент кода из класса **LinkedList** пакета **java.util**.

[image: Этот код находится внутри класса LinkedList пакета java.util]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> внутри статического контекста класса Node, мы получаем доступ через
> ключевое слово this к не статическим членам класса?

"Статический вложенный класс" - означает, что класс не привязан к объекту класса, который содержит это вложенное oпределение классa. И все. Никакого отношения к [не]статическим полям/методам вложенного класса это не имеет.

Comment: Первое утверждение, вроде как понимаю, что статический вложенный класс не ведает об объекте, созданном на основе внешнего класса. Второе утверждение не совсем понимаю, что Вы имеете в виду, пожалуйста разъясните.

Comment: @a66ac Это Вы завели речь о "не статических членах класса". Я написал, что тот факт, что вложенный класс - статический, не имеет отношения к доступу к его обычным или статическим полям.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что для статического метода, это имеет место быть, но не распространяется на статический вложенный класс?

Comment: @a66ac Я не понимаю, что "это"?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что из статического контекста метода, я не смогу обратиться к нестатическим полям. Дело в том, если я обращаюсь в контексте статического вложенного класса к не статическим полям, у меня это выходит, так как я обращаюсь к этим полям не непосредственно из статического вложенного класса, а из его не статического члена. Тем самым внутренний контекст члена перекрывает внешний.

Comment: @a66ac Я опять ничего не понял. На мой взгляд, использование ключевого слова `static` для вложенных классов было не очень удачным решением авторов этого элемента языка.

Comment: Скорее всего, я что то не так понимаю. Спасибо за помощь, что думаете по поводу первого вопроса, есть соображения?

Comment: @a66ac Они вложенные и приватные, потому что это детали реализации, которые не должны быть видны снаружи. А статический `Node` потому, что ему не нужен доступ к объекту родительского класса.